# Asp.Net Core 5.0: How to delete the connexion with an Azure Database SQL?

Tags: asp.net, azure-sql-database

I deployed my Asp.Net Core 5.0 application in Azure with Visual Studio, but now I dont have the subscription anymore.

I just deployed it on a Linux server in Apache but I think the connexion between my application and the Azure Database is still present because my app continue to ask me after a connectionString.

So I wanted to remove the connexion with the Azure Database SQL but I dont find where to do that.

How is it possible please ?

Answer (score 1):

To disconnect your .net core application with the Azure SQL-DB,

Try to remove/change the **connection string** name which  is used to connect with the **Azure SQL-database**.

The database context uses a connection string named Ex:`MyDbConnection`.

This connection string is set in the *Web.config* file and referenced in the *Models/MyDatabaseContext.cs* file.